# what is and how to get the nibName in "AppDelegate -> rootViewController = initWithNibName(NSString*)nibName"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, appdelegate

I would like to know what is the nibName in the method initWithNibname:(NSString*)nibName in the AppDelegate.m?

How it works?

What do I need to have in the method viewDidLoad in my ViewController that I want like rootViewController?

```
 @implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

   _tonten = [[TontenViewController alloc] init]; 
   //- I'm not sure about this either.

   self.window.rootViewController = [[TontenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tontenViewController" bundle:nil];


  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

Thanks for your attention and help!

Comment: I think , your nib name may be `TontenViewController`. Check case sense of nib name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`initWithNibName(NSString*)nibName` in this method nibName is name of your XIB.
```

say you have XIB named `TontenViewController.xib` then you can instantiate your view controller using this code

```
_tonten = [[TontenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TontenViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

`initWithNibname` is the name of your XIB.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

Returns a newly initialized view controller with the nib file in the specified bundle.

> **Parameters**
>
> *nibName*
>
> The name of the nib file to associate with the view controller. The
>   nib file name should not contain any leading path information. If you
>   specify nil, the nibName property is set to nil.
>
> *nibBundle*
>
> The bundle in which to search for the nib file. This method looks for
>   the nib file in the bundle's language-specific project directories
>   first, followed by the Resources directory. If this parameter is nil,
>   the method uses the heuristics described below to locate the nib file.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A newly initialized UIViewController object.

Comment: I read this lines in the Apple Documentations before have asking here. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

**nibName** is The name of the nib(XIB) file to associate with the view controller

you can do this in your appdelegate by following code

```
self.tonten = [[TontenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TontenViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tonten;
```